# ng-include work in firefox not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My Code Run only in Firefox not working in chrome.

**HTML Code**

```
<div ng-controller="myController1">

    Select View:
        <select ng-model="employeeview">
            <option value="1.html">1</option>
            <option value="2.html">2</option>
        </select>

        <div ng-include="employeeview"></div>
    </div>
```

**Angular Code**

```
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myController1', function($scope) {
            var employees = [
            {name: "Inderjeet", dateofbirth: new Date("November 23, 1980"), gender: "male", salery: "5000.788"},
            {name: "Ravi Pandey", dateofbirth: new Date("November 13, 1980"), gender: "male", salery: "5000.788"},
            {name: "Dilip", dateofbirth: new Date("November 30, 1991"), gender: "male", salery: "1000.000"},
            {name: "Deepika", dateofbirth: new Date("jan 25, 1980"), gender: "Female", salery: "50040.788"},
            {name: "Pradeep", dateofbirth: new Date("November 21, 1980"), gender: "male", salery: "5560.788"}
            ];
            $scope.employees = employees;
            $scope.employeeview = "1.html";


        });
```

**1.html content**

[1.html content i have attached in main file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyqPI.png)

**2.html**

Demo

Comment: chrome will not support cross origin files .If u  run a local server in a project it will work fine in all the browsers

Comment: run it on server. try `http-server`, it will deployed on localhost:8080 by default

Comment: Thanxx @CodeMan .... its work

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-ng-include="'views/employeeview.html'">
```

" ' ' " -- > u have to do like this

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS expression evaluating to URL. If the source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in single quotes, `e.g. src="'template.html'"`.

```
replace  $scope.employeeview = '1.html';
```

`ng-include="employeeview"`